# IdentityServer 4 User Registration - Where to place it?

Tags: angular, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I have an Angular 7 app that talks to IS4 via the oidc-client and also talks to a secured API. Everything is fine from the login and interaction point of view, however I wanted to implement user registration and I have read different opinions in different places regarding the question of

> where to place it?

Should it be in the IS4 app, should it be in the API? Some people say that IS should be "only" login/log-out and the rest should live elsewhere. Some others extend their own version of Identity Server and implement registration there.

I wouldn't be asking the question if I didn't want to LOG-IN automatically after a successful registration. I register my users in the DB via the API however I want to log them in against my IS. Now, I don't know if that's a good practice and assuming it is, whether I could simply use the SignInManager or should I call into the IS4 via HTTP or some other method. The other alternative would be to try to log in from my Angular app once the registration is successful however I'd like to bypass the log in screen and hit the endpoint with the payload directly. Does that make sense?

Any suggestions/ ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: To keep it simple you'd want to have the user registration where you have your users db. And if that's where IS4 is hosted then that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is the responsibility of IS, it is your one source of truth for Identity management tool. As soon as a user tries to access ur application, they will be redirected to login page I suppose and at the login screen, you can have new user registration link and have a different workflow in the IS app and once the user registration is done, you can navigate the user to the respective application. FYI, we did the same for our application and we did not see any downsides and the application is in prod for 7 months.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I was of the same opinion however I’ve read multiple views of different approaches achieving the same result. I like your design of login+sign up screens. I implemented it in a slightly different way because I wanted to have a different design for a registration screen avoiding the classic sign in screen then link to sign up, but definitely works on other sites I need to work on. Thanks for this!